# AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'map_dict' polars Document example error

Tags: python, python-polars

Taking the example straight from the docs:

```
country_code_dict = {
    "CA": "Canada",
    "DE": "Germany",
    "FR": "France",
    None: "Not specified",
}
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "country_code": ["FR", None, "ES", "DE"],
    }
).with_row_count()

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("country_code")
    .map_dict(country_code_dict, default="unknown")
    .alias("remapped")
)
```

here: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html

Gives the error: `AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'map_dict'`

Is there another way to do this mapping operation?

Comment: `map_dict` was added in [0.16.3](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.16.3): what's your version (`print(pl.__version__)`)?

Comment: @Timus you are correct, I should have checked this. I am using conda not pip so the latest version is not available to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the apply function instead of the map_dict function to achieve the mapping operation

```
    import polars as pl

country_code_dict = {
    "CA": "Canada",
    "DE": "Germany",
    "FR": "France",
    None: "Not specified",
}

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "country_code": ["FR", None, "ES", "DE"],
    }
)

def remap_country_code(code):
    if code is None:
        return country_code_dict[None]
    return country_code_dict.get(code, "unknown")

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("country_code")
    .apply(remap_country_code, return_dtype=pl.Utf8)
    .alias("remapped")
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
shape: (4, 2)

    ┌──────────────┬──────────┐
    │ country_code ┆ remapped │
    │ ---          ┆ ---      │
    │ str          ┆ str      │
    ╞══════════════╪══════════╡
    │ FR           ┆ France   │
    │ null         ┆ null     │
    │ ES           ┆ unknown  │
    │ DE           ┆ Germany  │

└──────────────┴──────────┘
```